# passing global data in partial views without duplicating code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have an application where I need to display a username and image for the current user. I could pull the data into a viewmodel and display in the view, however this would mean that i would need to do this in every controller that uses the view. Is there a way where I can global set values and call in some partial views without having to repeatedly duplicate it in each controller?

Comment: You can store those values in claims to avoid making db calls for every request. Inject a service directly into the view and fetch data from there. [Read more about DI into views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you need to call a child action from your _Layout.cshtml.  Here's how it could look.

First from what you have said I am assuming your viewModel will be this

```
public class UserDisplayViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

You will need a controller that is responsible for getting the username and image data.
It would look like this

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult _userDisplay()
    {           
        var viewModel = GetUserNameAndImage();
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    private UserDisplayViewModel GetUserNameAndImage()
    {
      //code for getting the username and image data
    }
}
```

You would call the child action from your _layout.cshtml file like this

```
 @Html.Action("_userDisplay", "User")
```

It goes wherever you want the username and image to appear in your HTML.

You will also need a partial view called _userDisplay.cshtml which will contain the markup for how you want to display your username and image.  Here's a very basic example

```
@model UserDisplayViewModel
@{    
    Layout = null;
}

<p>
    Username: @Model.UserName
</p>

<p>
    <img src="@Model.ImageUrl"/>
</p>
```